# SSRS Having One Parameter Filter the Values in The Second Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012

I'm slowly making progress in my SSRS Report.  I've added a couple of parameters, each one of them work fine in filtering the data based on the selected values (both allow multiple values).  Now I want to have one parameters selected values change or filter the available values in the second parameter.  I'll include some pictures to hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do and with what.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I want to populate the second parameter dropdown of SubCategories based on the selected Categories in the first dropdown.

The problem is I am unsure of how to do it so that I don't get the
*"One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified error"*

I got that above error by trying to add a parameter in the dataset query through a WHERE clause in the following Query in the SubCategory Dataset

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SubCategory WHERE CategoryId = (@Category)
```

I'm not sure how I would apply that so it's pulling tha value(s) from the Category Parameter.

I anticipate another challenge being that both accept multiple values, so I have to structure it so that it takes the appropriate amount of parameters.

Sorry for the potentially dumb questions, I'm fresh to SQL and even fresher to SSRS.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SubCategory WHERE CategoryId IN (@Category)
```

`@Category` is a multiple value parameter.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro, I made the change and I did it in the appropriate location this time.